# Using 'this' in nested Scala Class definition

Tags: scala, oop

I have the following abstract class with the method :: and the inner class ListNode

```
abstract class SimpleList[+Elem] {
  def head: Elem
  def tail: SimpleList[Elem]
  def isEmpty: Boolean

  def ::[NewElem >: Elem] (newHead: NewElem): SimpleList[NewElem] = new ListNode(hd= newHead, tl= this)

  private class ListNode[Elem](hd: Elem, tl: SimpleList[Elem]) extends SimpleList[Elem] {
    override def head = hd
    override def tail = tl
    override def isEmpty = false

object SimpleList {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    val squareNumbers = 1 :: 4 :: 9 :: 16 :: Empty
  }
}
```

The :: method uses 'this' to define a new ListNode.

As you can see in the main method, the :: method is invoked.
It seems like it creates a new ListNode from 1 and 4 etc.

However I dont understand what the 'this' keyword refernces in this case.
Does it reference the 4?
And what is a SimpleList in this defintion?
A custom data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two questions and that is what is causing you confusion. The first thing is what does `this` means, well it means *this* object, the current instance where the method was called. Which makes sense, since prepending an element to a **List** is just create a new one where the passed element is the head and the current one is the tail.

Now the second question is how that works in the main, differently to most methods `::` is called on the right-hand side and the argument passed is the left-hand side *(this is specified on the language specs, every method that ends with colons `:` will behave like that)*.
So you have to see the code like this:

```
// The operations are applied in this order
1 :: (2 :: (3 :: (4 :: Empty)))

// And thus it is the same as
Empty.::(4).::(3).::(2).::(1)

// Which is easier to see like this
val res0 = Empty // Empty
val res1 = res0.::(4) // 4 :: Empty - (head = 4, tail / this = res0)
val res2 = res1.::(3) // 3 :: (4 :: Empty) - (head = 3, tail / this = res1)
val res3 = res2.::(2) // 2 :: (3 :: (4 :: Empty)) - (head = 2, tail / this = res2)
val res4 = res3.::(1) // 1 :: (2 :: (3 :: (4 :: Empty))) - (head = 1, tail / this = res3)
```

So you can see that when we create the final **List** we are creating the **List** whose head is `1` and its tail was `2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Empty` because we called the `::` method on that previous **List**.

---

For your final question, yes **CustomList** is a custom data structure, an abstract class, a new type, etc.
You should already understand that if you want to continue with more complex topics.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared a lot up. So did I understand it correctly that ```this``` refernces (2 :: (3 :: (4 :: Empty))) in this example? Which in turn has the type SimpleList?

Comment: @gython yes in the final call `this` is `2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Empty` because that is the object on which you are calling the method. But in the previous call it was ``3 :: 4 :: Empy` since that was the object it which the method was called. See the edited answer.